# The Components of two Forces Along the Axis are Equal

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors

I have a doubt in understanding the meaning of this statement written on my homework.

> The components $F_1$ and $F_3$ are equal along the u-axis

Does the statement mean that the x and y components of those two forces are really equal?

[image]

Comment: *Does the statement mean that the x and y components of those two forces are really equal?* By looking at the diagram you can see that they are not. The statement is about the $u$ components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the question states that components of F1 and F3 are equal along u as an axis, ie measure the angle along u axis and take components.

Comment: Does it mean that the u-components of F1 and F3 are the ones that are equal? ie. F_(1u) = F_(3u)?

Comment: Yes, i think @Eli 's last statement is the eqn

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The components of $F_1$ and $F_2$ along u axis are not equal because the angle $\alpha$ is not equal to the angle $\beta$, the question supposed to be find the components of $F_2$ along u ?

$$F_1\cos(\alpha)=F_2\cos(\beta)$$